# How can I regulate a speedof rotation tile icon?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

How can I regulate a speed of rotation tile icon? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you talking about the tile of a pinned app on the home screen? The speed and timing of the rotation is controled by the System, you can't change that...